# A picture frame measures $14$ cm by $20$ cm. $160$ cm$^2$ of the picture shows inside the frame. Find the width of the frame.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, geometric-interpretation

> A picture frame measures $14$cm by $20$cm. $160$cm$^2$ of the picture shows inside the frame. Find the width of the frame.

This is the question I was given, word-for-word. Is it asking for the width of the picture? Becuase the way I see it, the width is simply $14$...

EDIT: Is this the correct interpretation? (Sorry did a really quick drawing in MS paint, red represents what I am supposed to find)
[image]

Comment: No, no, think of a painting with a frame around it, like the outer black bit in [this](http://www.framedcanvasart.com/product/starry-night.html). The question says that total width of the picture + frame is 14, and the total length of the same is 20, and wants the width of just the frame.

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Your picture does not show that the frame is the same width on the horizontal and vertical sides, but you need to assume that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know what a picture frame looks like, right?  Two concentric rectangles.

You are given the dimensions of the outer rectangle.  You are given the area of the inner rectangle.

You are asked to find the thickness of the border between them.

$$20\textrm{cm}\left\{ \vphantom{\bbox[green, 2ex, border:solid 1pt]{\bbox[white, 1ex, border:solid 1pt]{\begin{array}{l}\qquad\\160\textrm{cm}^2\\~\\~\end{array}}}} \right.
%
\overbrace{\bbox[green, 2ex, border:solid 1pt]{\bbox[white, 1ex, border:solid 1pt]{\begin{array}{l}\qquad\\160\textrm{cm}^2\\~\\~\end{array}}}}^{14\textrm{cm}}$$

Comment: Your picture looks pretty similar to mine; is mine correct?

Comment: Yes. Indeed it is.

Comment: So I think the "width" you want is the length of the of the red line segment that you drew between the inner and outer rectangles in the question. Yeah, that was quite an obtusely worded problem someone gave you.

Answer (score 7):

You are expected to assume that the picture frame has a constant width.  That width creates a border around the picture.  Note that the area of the frame is $280 \text{ cm}^2$, which is larger than the picture.  You are supposed to find th width of the frame.

Answer (score 3):

The question pretty ambiguous.  My interpretation would be that you have a rectangular picture frame whose exterior dimensions are $14\times 20$.  The frame has uniform width, so all sides are the same width.  If you place a picture in the frame then $160$ square cm of the picture will be visible.  What is the width of a side of the frame?

Answer (score 1):

$$(14-2w)(20-2w)=160.$$

This quadratic equations has the two solutions $w=2$ and $w=15$; the latter must naturally be rejected.

Hence the width is $2$ cm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that's what you have to solve.
So, if your picture frame's constant width is x cm, you can get this;

14*20=160+2(14-x)x+2(20-x)x

280=160+28x-2x^2+40x-2x^2

4x^2-68x-120=0

x^2-17x+30=0

(x-15)(x-2)=0

x=2 or 15

But, x<14

Therefore, x=2

2cm