# A picture frame measures $14$cm by $20$cm. $160$cm$^2$ of the picture shows inside the frame. Find the width of the frame.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> A picture frame measures $14$cm by $20$cm. $160$cm$^2$ of the picture shows inside the frame. Find the width of the frame.

I [know how to interpret it now](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016177/what-is-this-word-problem-asking?noredirect=1#comment4138969_2016177), but how do I solve it? The equation I made from this is $$(14-2x)(20-2x)=\frac 23\cdot14\cdot20$$which solves into $$x = \dfrac{17\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{587}3}}{2}$$but this looks incorrect

Comment: Are you sure about your equation?

Comment: Not completely sure...

Comment: The LHS of your equation is good, but the RHS should be $160$ (that's the area after all!). So we'd have $$(14-2x)(20-2x)=160$$ which we may simplify to $$(7-x)(10-x)=40$$ and eyeballing it yields $x=2$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning comment into answer per request.

The LHS of your equation is good, but the RHS should be $160$ (that's the area after all!). We'd have $$(14-2x)(20-2x)=160$$ which we may simplify to $$(7-x)(10-x)=40$$ Eyeballing it yields $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $h$ is the width of the frame then:

\begin{equation}
120=2(14-2h)h+2(20-2h)h+4h^2
\end{equation}

where 120 is the area of the frame. $4h^2$ is the area of the corners (they are squares), the other terms represent the area of the four rectangles left.

Comment: Can you explain how you got this equation? Thanks